# Function type to reference to function type: undefined reference

Tags: c++

Why am I getting an undefined reference error for this code:

```
int foo() { return 5; }

int main()
{
   int bar(int() = foo);
   bar();
}

int bar(int (&x)())
{
    return x();
}
```

But when I use this code it compiles fine:

```
void baz(int (&)()) {}
int foo() { return 5;}

int main()
{
   baz(foo);
}
```

Comment: Because you haven't got a forward declaration for `bar`.

Comment: if you get an "undefined reference to __XYZ" then the first piece of code **compiles** fine too.

Comment: @OliCharlesworthi I have a forward declaration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
undefined reference to `bar(int (*)())'
```

And what you have is:

```
int bar(int (&x)())
```